# dotnet 7 how to exclude some exe when using IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

In dotnet 6/7, you can set a flag, `IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract`, to include native libraries in the single file bundle. These files are extracted to a directory in the client machine when the single file application is run.
However, I found the flag would also make my extern exe file included in the bundle.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Update="extern_tool\clash.exe" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

My program will crash as it can't find the location of `clash.exe`.
so, How to exclude some exe file when using `IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract`?

Comment: Any reason you don't just pick up the tool from where it's presumably extracted? Using `Path.GetDirectory(Environment.ProcessPath)` as the base should do it. Alternatively, if your executable isn't included in the bundle at all but will later be copied near the packed bundle, use `AppContext.BaseDirectory`. A path relative to the working directory should probably never be used.

Comment: @JeroenMostert `clash.exe` is not extracted to `Path.GetDirectory(Environment.ProcessPath)`.

Comment: Is it copied anywhere at all? If not this might need a custom build step (I'm not sure how the single file package logic works). Step one of getting it to work is making the file available at all; it's only step two that's actually finding it at runtime.